# Calling a Fragment method from a parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I see in the [Android Fragments Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) that an "activity can call methods in a fragment by acquiring a reference to the Fragment from FragmentManager, using `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()`."

The example that follows shows how to get a fragment reference, but not how to call specific methods in the fragment.

Can anyone give an example of how to do this?  I would like to call a specific method in a Fragment from the parent Activity.  Thanks.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

not get the question exactly as it is too simple  :

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.<specific_function_name>();
```

Comment: OK that was easy, thanks (I'm brand new to fragments).  Now the hard part is I can't seem to get a reference to the fragment in the first place.  It's not defined in an XML layout, so I can't use findFragmentById().  And it's not clear to me from the code I'm following (ref above) how/where the fragment is even created.  If it were I could just add a tag and use findFragmentByTag().  The AccountListActivity part of the example does have a call to beginTransaction().add(), but per my trace it's never called.  This is where I am scratching my head.  I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I left out the reference.  The code pattern I am following is [FragmentTabsPager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html).  Thanks.

Comment: The situation will be different when neither u are having the ID nor the TAG associated with the fragment .

Comment: how can I get the fragment id?

Comment: By doing this i ended up in a null object reference!

Comment: look in your **<fragment tag** in the xml file.  You must have an id in there. It would be "example_fragment" to match the example code given.

Comment: @Fattie , what if I don't have fragment tag?

Comment: i'm pretty sure you have to, @VaclovasRekašiusJr. !  **search through your XML files**

Comment: I didn't declared fragment in xml... so i dont have fragment id, What will i do ??

Comment: In Kotlin use such syntax to suppress "this cast can never success" warning

  `val fragm : MyFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment) as MyFragment`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ...

I got this error when tried with your solution.

Comment: getFragmentManger is now deprecated , Use FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 82):

If you are using “import android.app.Fragment;”
Then use either:

1)

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment); 
fragment.specific_function_name();
```

Where R.id.example_fragment is most likely the FrameLayout id inside your xml layout. 
OR

2)

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(“FragTagName”); 
fragment.specific_function_name();
```

Where FragTagName is the name u specified when u did:

```
TabHost mTabHost.newTabSpec(“FragTagName”)
```

---

If you are using “import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;”
Then use either:

1)

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment); 
fragment.specific_function_name();
```

OR

2)

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(“FragTagName”); 
fragment.specific_function_name();
```

Comment: I have a CoordinatorLayout with id R.id.example_fragment, its returning null. I'm using import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; what to do?

Comment: I suggest you post this as a new question and include your sample code. It's hard to tell the source of the problem without seeing the actual code.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using a support library, you'll want to do something like this:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment);
fragment.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 7):

Too late for the question but this is a easy way to get fragment instance and call methods in a fragment; you have to get instance of your fragment then call your public method:

In your fragment :

```
 private static yourFragment instance;
```

then in `onCreateView` of your fragment :

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        instance= this;

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tools, container, false);
        binding = FragmentToolsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        return v;
    }
```

and also in your fragment you have to have a static method that returns the instance:

```
public static yourFragment GetInstance()
{
    return instance;
}
```

then you have a public method in in your fragment that you want to call it like this:

```
public  void  theMethod()
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

then you can get fragment instance and call your non static public method like this:

```
   yourFragment frag = yourFragment.GetInstance();
   frag.theMethod();
```

Comment: you didnt use directly a public instance. is it because it helps for memory allocation if you use statc method with private static variable?

Comment: Hi da jowkar, I was tried many methods. Finally your method is working like a charm!!!. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

1. If you're not using a support library Fragment, then do the following:

`((FragmentName) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id)).methodName();`

2. If you're using a support library Fragment, then do the following:

`((FragmentName) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id)).methodName();`

Answer (score 5):

**From fragment to activty:**

```
((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod();
```

**From activity to fragment:**

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

```
//if you added fragment via layout xml
YourFragmentClass fragment = 
(YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
fragment.yourPublicMethod();
```

If you added fragment via code and used a **tag** string when you added your fragment, use **findFragmentByTag** instead:

```
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentByTag("yourTag");
```

Answer (score 4):

you also call fragment method using interface like

first you create interface

```
public interface InterfaceName {
    void methodName();
}
```

after creating interface you implement interface in your fragment

```
MyFragment extends Fragment implements InterfaceName {
    @overide
    void methodName() {

    }
}
```

and you create the reference of interface in your activity

```
class Activityname extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button click;
    MyFragment fragment;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        click = findViewById(R.id.button);

        fragment = new MyFragment();

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               fragment.methodName();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best is to check if fragment is added before calling method in fragment. Do something like this to avoid null exception.

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
if(fragment.isAdded()){
  fragment.<specific_function_name>(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you create method  in your `fragment` like

```
public void name()
{


}
```

in your `activity` you add this

add `onCreate()` method

```
myfragment fragment=new myfragment()
```

finally call the method where you want to call  add this

```
fragment.method_name();
```

try this code

Answer (score 1):

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
MainFragment frag = (MainFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment); 
frag.<specific_function_name>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `Java`, but in `C#` (Xamarin.Android) there is no need to look up the fragment everytime you need to call the method, see below:

```
public class BrandActivity : Activity
{
    MyFragment myFragment;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {       
        // ...
        myFragment = new MyFragment();      
        // ...
    }

    void someMethod()
    {
        myFragment.MyPublicMethod();
    }
}

public class MyFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void MyPublicMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }   
}
```

I think in `Java` you can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
((HomesFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)).filterValidation();
```

Comment: Please, feel free to explain why this solves the problem in a better way than the previously accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the question but will post my answer anyway for anyone still needs it.
I found an easier way to implement this, without using fragment id or fragment tag, since that's what I was seeking for.

First, I declared my Fragment in my ParentActivity class:

```
MyFragment myFragment;
```

Initialized my viewPager as usual, with the fragment I already added in the class above.
Then, created a public method called **scrollToTop** in myFragment that does what I want to do from ParentActivity, let's say scroll my recyclerview to the top.

```
public void scrollToTop(){
    mMainRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
}
```

Now, in ParentActivity I called the method as below:

```
try{
   myFragment.scrollToTop();
}catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in my case hope anyone get help from this

```
OnDemandFrag frag = new OnDemandFrag();
```

using this to replace fragment in main

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, frag).commit();
```

i just created a global instance of fragment in the MainActivity and then from this instance run function of Fragment

```
frag.hidelayer();
```