# How to call a method on a Fragment of Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

**Activity method of fragment call as follows:**

```
MyActivity method = (MyActivity) getActivity (); 
method.MyMethod ("string");
```

**Here's how it looks in the Activity:**

```
public void MyMethod (String var) 
{         
    Toast.makeText (MyActivity.this,                  
        var,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

**Question. How to call a method on a Fragment of Activity? (Ie, reverse)**

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Activity's FragmentManager to get the active instance of your fragment, and continue as usual.

For example:

MyFragment.java:

```
public void FragmentMethod() {
    doSomethingInFragment();
}
```

Activity.java:

```
public void onCreate() {
    FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment)fragManager.getFragments().get(0);
    fragment.FragmentMethod();
}
```

You'll notice that I retrieved the instance of the fragment using `getFragments().get(0)`, which refers to the first fragment in your FragmentManager's back stack. If you only have one fragment this is OK, otherwise you can use the `getFragment(Bundle, String)` method.

Comment: If you're using the v4 support library, try calling getSupportFragmentManager() instead

Comment: OK, that means that you're using fragments from the regular API. I highly recommend using the v4 fragments as they are supported by more devices. Get the **android-support-v4.jar** library file, place it in your libs directory and replace all the fragment references from android.app to **android.support.v4.app**. This is generally recommended and will also enable the solution to work :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to instantiate the fragment (get an instance of the fragment) and then call the method.

Comment: I use SectionsPagerAdapter. when you select a specific section of a fragment is created: return new LoadObjects (); but if I do this: LoadObjects frag = new LoadObjects (); FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager (). BeginTransaction (); transaction.add (R.id.fragment_container, frag, "listFragment"); transaction.commit (); return frag; application is closed

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly why not just create public method in fragment and just call it?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
...
       public void myMethod (String var){         
             Toast.makeText (getActivity(),var,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       } 
}
```

And in your activity:

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
...
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.content_frame_layout, fragment);
fragment.myMethod("your string");
```

Comment: Have you got **android-support-v4.jar** in **libs** folder?

Comment: If not, you need to download it and just put it into **libs** folder. Try to download the latest **android-support-v4.jar** with the Android SDK Manager and then copy the jar from `<sdkdir>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`