# Calling Fragment's method from Activity doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity) question and tried my hand at calling a method which is in my Fragment. I'm trying to call the method from an activity. However it's not recognizing the fragment's method. Here's my code:

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/peoplefragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/searchpeople_list"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:background="#fff">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment Code:**

```
    public class SearchPeopleTab extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {          
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_people_tab, container, false);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_people_tab, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        public static void UpdateResults(String requestSearch)
        {
               new GetSearchResults(requestSearch).execute();
        }

class GetSearchResults extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String requestSearch;

        GetSearchResults(String searchtext)
        {
            this.requestSearch = searchtext;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    }
```

**Activity Code: (Calling the Fragment's method)**

```
 private void PopulateResults() {

        FragmentManager manager = (FragmentManager) getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.peoplefragment);
        fragment.UpdateResults(requestSearch); //thats the method in the fragment. 

}
```

The 'UpdateResults()' part is underlined and the following message is given as an error:

> Cannot resolve method UpdateResults()

Looks like it can't find the method. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Remove the keyword `static`** from the method.
2. And also, store the fragment in the **`SearchPeopleTab` reference variable**, that you created.

   You don't really need the line to store the `FragmentManager`, you can directly use `getSupportFragmentManager();`

   ```
   //FragmentManager fm = (FragmentManager) getSupportFragmentManager();
   SearchPeopleTab fragment = (SearchPeopleTab) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.peoplefragment);
   fragment.UpdateResults();
   ```

When static methods are used, they are called using the class name. **When you want a method to be called on specific objects, the method should not be static.**

Comment: What if I want to send a parameter to the method as well? as in fragment.UpdateResults("hey");

Comment: Yes, Works the same way. `fragment.UpdateResults("hey");`

If this was the solution, please do mark the answer as accepted. Helps me gain reputation points. :) Thank you.

Comment: Yes, and do change the code for the method in the fragment too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the Fragment to your defined class

```
private void PopulateResults() {

    FragmentManager manager = (FragmentManager) getSupportFragmentManager();
    SearchPeopleTab fragment = (SearchPeopleTab)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.peoplefragment);
    fragment.UpdateResults(); //thats the method in the fragment. 

}
```

Comment: What if I want to send a parameter to the method as well? as in fragment.UpdateResults("hey"); It returns a null pointer

Comment: Just declare the method to take a String parameter. Do you get the null pointer when you call UpdateResults()? If so, can you show the code for that method?

Comment: Updated the question :) I believe it must be because I'm trying to call AsyncTask from a static method