# how to add view to fragment in onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I'm using a `ViewPager` in my Activity which has multiple Fragments. in the `onCreate` method of my Activity, I want to add multiple views to one of those fragments so that they can be seen at start. the problem is that i can not find a way to access that fragment. how to do that? I have tried to access the `RecyclerView` of that fragment at this way:

```
public class CaafeFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView = null;

public CaafeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_caafe, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.caafeRecyclerView);
    return view;
}

public RecyclerView getRecyclerView() {
    return (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.caafeRecyclerView);
}
}
```

but it returns null when i call `getRecyclerView()` from the `onCreate()` of my activity

// activity

```
public void onCreate()
{
 .
 .
 .
 CaafeFragment caafeFragment=new CaafeFragment();
 caafeRecyclerView = caafeFragment.getRecyclerView(); // here it returns null
}
```

Comment: Please post the code where u are trying to access the recyclerview from the activity

Comment: sure it returns null, `onCreateView` in the fragment wasn't called.

Comment: @JörnBuitink, yes, u r correct, but what is the solution?!!!

Answer (score 1):

After the `onCreate()` is called (in the Fragment), the Fragment's `onCreateView()` is called due to this is throws error as **you have declared recycleview in onCreate() method.**

Check [onCreate(), onCreateView() difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929637/difference-and-uses-of-oncreate-oncreateview-and-onactivitycreated-in-fra) for more detail.

### ex:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.<specific_function_name>();
```

Comment: just as u said, it seems clear that `onCreateView()` is not called at that stage. how to solve it?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity

Answer (score 1):

```
CaafeFragment caafeFragment=new CaafeFragment();
```

caafeFragment points to nothing, it should refer a fragment, this line just creates fragment object. You are trying to get something that it does not contain. You should specify which fragment that object holds:

```
CaafeFragment caafeFragment=(CaafeFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.YOUR_FRAGMENT_ID);

caafeRecyclerView = caafeFragment.getRecyclerView();
```

Now the caafeFragment object contains something you can access from.

**EDIT**

You should return the `private RecyclerView recyclerView` object that you set via "view"  in OnCreate(),

in getRecyclerView()

replace <strike>return (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.caafeRecyclerView);</strike>
by:

```
public RecyclerView getRecyclerView() {
    return recyclerView;
}
```

What is certain here is that recyclerView object holds view that is instantiated, and this line can be tracked to make sure that, in onCreate(),

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.caafeRecyclerView);
```

Has value or not.

Comment: but i add the created fragment to a viewpager

Comment: Also have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager

Comment: You can try this to get fragments: http://tamsler.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-viewpager-and-fragments-part-ii.html