# How to call fragment method from main activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragmentmanager

I have method in fragment class. I want to call that method from main activity but I don't want to use FragmentById (or) FragmentByTag.

My fragment method:

```
public void setItemFromDrawer(String sourceTag, String destTag) {
    //dosomething
}
```

How to call above method from main activity without using FragmentById (or) FragmentByTag?

Comment: when you load fragment using fragmentTransaction save fragment object and later on you can call any public method from that object

Comment: I didn't understand.. Can you give any example code

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity?rq=1

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73796270/13560080

Answer (score 40):

First create an interface

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    void myAction() ;
}
```

Your fragment must implement this interface.

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyInterface
```

In your activity, **define a field of type MyInterface** :

```
  private MyInterface listener ;

  public void setListener(MyInterface listener)
  {
     this.listener = listener ;
  }
```

When creating your fragment and adding it :

```
setListener(myFragment);
```

Finally, when the condtion happens that you want to call the Fragment method, just call :

```
listener.myAction() ; // this will call the implementation in your MyFragment class.
```

Comment: I always find interfaces effective and the best option. This is the answer I'll recommend more.

Comment: Simple and best answer!

Comment: `setListener(myFragment);` - where do you set that???????

Comment: When creating your fragment and adding it! in your activity. @ekashking

Comment: What if I add it in ViewPager?

Answer (score 9):

it means your calling a fragment method

```
((YourFragmentClass) fragment).Yourmethod();
```

Answer (score 8):

To better explain the answer by **user5466222** :

```
YourFragmentClass fragment = new YourFragmentClass();
((YourFragmentClass) fragment).yourmethod();
```

Comment: If it was just that easy .... but it's not. `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 2):

In Activity use something like this where you load your fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(container, fragment);

transaction.addToBackStack(null); // if you want to store transaction        
transaction.commit();
currentFragment = fragment; // currentFragment is global Fragment variable
```

Use following line where you want to call fragment's method

```
currentFragment.setItemFromDrawer("sourceTag","destTag");
```

Comment: currentFragment = fragment; In this line fragment is what?

Comment: the fragment you are loading. in which your function implemented

Answer (score -2):

((YourFragment Class) fragment).Your method();

its worked form me

Comment: fragment meant what?