# Hiding or showing button from different context

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-context

I want to modify the visibility of an `ImageView` which is located in the layout of an activity, from a fragment which is loaded in a container inside parent activity's layout.

In a parent activity class I have this method:

```
public void enableAddEvvOkBtn(boolean mHide, Activity mActivity) {
    view = getView();
    if(mHide) btnAddEvVOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else btnAddEvVOk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

and in the fragment I am calling the method:

```
tabSketch.enableAddEvvOkBtn(true, getActivity());
```

where tabSketch is an instance of the parent activity.

However this is not working, I think it must be something related to the context how can I make this work?

Comment: use interface as a callback to the activity from fragment then hide or show

Comment: apply this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/35747982/2450855

Comment: that did the trick, thanks a bunch @FarhadFaghihi

Comment: Followed this [stackoverflow.com/a/35747982/2450855](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35747982/2450855) approach pointed by @FarhadFaghihi

Comment: Glad I could help :) @Juanca

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make Visible/Gone more simple

`btnAddEvVOk.setVisibility(btnAddEvVOk.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE)`;

This makes the Button visible if=gone and gone if= visible

Comment: keeps stopping, this instruction is inside the method right?

Comment: 'public void enableAddEvvOkBtn(boolean mHide, Activity mActivity) {
    view = getView();
    if(mHide) btnAddEvVOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else btnAddEvVOk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}' instead of this you can use 'public void setButtonVisibility(){  btnAddEvVOk.setVisibility(btnAddEvVOk.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); }