# Unable to reference `fragment` using `R.id.myFirstFragment`

Tags: android, android-fragments, r.java-file

Here is the class of fragment

```
package com.hfad.chapter7;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private long workoutID;


    public WorkoutDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
    }


    public void setWorkoutID(long workoutID) {
        this.workoutID = workoutID;
    }
}
```

And the layout it's using is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hfad.chapter7.WorkoutDetailFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

My `MainActivity` is:

```
package com.hfad.chapter7;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.provider.UserDictionary;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WokoutDetailFragment workoutDetailFragment;
        workoutDetailFragment = (WorkoutDetailFragment)this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFirstFragment);


    }
}
```

And layout of `MainActivity` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.hfad.chapter7.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />

    <fragment
        class="com.hfad.chapter7.WorkoutDetailFragment"
        android:id="@+id/myFirstFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is when I use `this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFirstFragment)` in onCreate of `AppCompatActivity` I get `Fragment` though I should get `WorkoutDetailFragment` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10903140/4913383) in a similar example.

## UPDATE:

Also I am unable to cast `Fragment` to `WorkDetailFragment`
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead? Or does your Fragment class not extend the v4 Fragment?

Comment: Please include the imports for your Fragment and someone will explain why you can't cast

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks a lot, using `getSupportFragmentManager() fixed the problem. Would be great if you can point to some resource or explain why did it work?

Comment: It's confusing, but there are several `Fragment` classes, you have to import the right one. Read the other answers in the post you linked to. (the second part of this one).    http://stackoverflow.com/a/25416259/2308683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user4913383,

Change this line:

```
workoutDetailFragment = (WorkoutDetailFragment)this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFirstFragment);
```

to

```
workoutDetailFragment = (WorkoutDetailFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFirstFragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem of getting a fragment? The `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` method returns a `Fragment` and you have to cast it.  Since you are casting the `Fragment` to a `WorkoutDetailFragment` you should be able to do what you want with it.

Comment: I think what he wants to say is that the cast fails.

Comment: Please have look at question I have updated it. @Lucas

Comment: @user4913383, I have posted the answer. Check it.

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty You are totally right. Just saw the support library import. Your code should work

Comment: @LucasP., If u think so, I would like you to please upvote the answer as it might be helpful for others. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be `<fragment android:name="com.hfad.chapter7.WorkoutDetailFragment"...` instead of `class`.
=> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout