# getActivity() returns null on fragment?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment

I have `MainActivity()` and a `FirstFragment()`.

I'm calling a function which is in FirstFragment from `MainActivity()`.

The problem is, that time `getActivity()` returns null ?

Comment: show your code please .

Comment: Post how you are loading fragment in activity?

Comment: I think you are asking same, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity

Comment: you should rad about Fragment lifecycle. There are some states where getActivity is OK to return null.

Comment: if (isNetworkAvailable(getActivity()))
        {
                                System.out.println("Internet is On.");

        }

Comment: @PriyankaG : Update your question with code so that everyone can see it.

Comment: I think you should pass context try getActivity.getcontext()

Comment: Your reference site helps me alot. Thanks. Sanjeev

Answer (score 4):

Do this when fragment start

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mcontext=getContext();
```

mcontext will easily be casted as activity if you need it.

Since Android API level 23, onAttach(Activity activity) has been deprecated. You need to use onAttach(Context context). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)
so if you want to use onattach you need to do

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Activity a;
    if (context instanceof Activity){
         a=(Activity) context;
    }
}
```

**do not do**

```
  if(getActivity()==null){
```

get activity will return null when you move the app to the background and return.
if you use this it will just ignore this part of the code sometimes which will create bugs you won't understand where they come from.

Answer (score 3):

Please use `Activity` reference from `onAttach()`. I think this is the best pratice to use instance of `Activity` from Fragment

```
 public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
 private Activity mActivity;
     @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            mActivity = (Activity) context;//use this one .. this is MainActivity instance u can use this as MainActivity mMainActivity = (MainActivity)mActivity;
        }
  }
```

Comment: From what I have read else where, this is just a bandaid kind of fix. Because holding an activity reference could cause the whole activity to leak. What an ideal solution will be to not do any actions on the activity object reference when it is null.

Answer (score 2):

```
// declare a variable activity in your fragment
private Activity activity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
    }

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    this.activity = null;
}


private void initToolbar() {

    // then use the var in any function
    if (activity == null) {
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Activity reference. You can create reference of Context class.

```
private Context context;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Activity) {//Name of your activity
        this.context = (Activity) context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass `context` try like this

```
if(isNetworkAvailable(getActivity().getContext())) 
{
    System.out.println("Internet is On.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
mContext = context;
}
```

Then in the where you want to call function in 'MainActivity' like this:

```
((MainActivity)mContext).theFunctionYouWanToCall();
```

or if the fragment could belong to more than one activities, then check first:

```
if(MainActivity instanceOf mContext)
  ((MainActivity)mContext).theFunctionYouWanToCall();
```

Hope this help!