# Limited access in 2nd fragment of FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have two similar by `onViewCreated` structure fragments

```
//1st
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    textDebug1 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view_debug1); //from layout1
    textDebug2 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view_debug2); //from layout2
//2nd
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    textDebug1 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view_debug1); //<--gives  error; layout1
    textDebug2 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view_debug2); //from layout2
```

in onCreateView for both I have same line but different layouts.

```
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag_main, container, false);
```

`TextView`s are located on different layouts and if I choose to load 1st fragment then code works well, but if I choose 2nd to run 1st then `getActivity()` returns `null`. What might cause this if creation is identical for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Fragment lifecycle, you'll see that there's an `onAttach()` and an `onDetach()` methods. They refer to the Fragment's state. Since you're using a ViewPager, your fragments might be detached and the `getActivity()` might return `null`.

As stated [on this article](http://www.t3hmun.com/posts/2017-01-24_Fragment-Life-Cycle-in-a-ViewPager.html), this is what happens with a Fragment inside a ViewPager:

> When the page is no longer visible or adjacent to the visible page the
>   ViewPager asks the adapter to destroy it. However the
>   FragmentPagerAdapter doesn't destroy the fragment entirely. It calls
>   **FragmentTransaction.detach(fragment)**, which destroys the fragment's
>   entire view hierarchy, but not the object. Next time the ViewPager
>   wants that page the same fragment object can be retrieved and the view
>   is rebuilt. In the process the onCreateView() is called again, this is
>   where your logic to initialise the view belongs.

And as stated [on the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Lifecycle):

> Caution: If you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can call getContext(). However, be careful to call getContext() only when the fragment is attached to an activity. **When the fragment isn't attached yet, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle, getContext() returns null**.

One thing you can try is to retain the fragment instance. Inside your Fragment's `onCreate()`, try to call the method `setRetainInstance(true);`

Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363283/4070469) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state/9646622#9646622) here on SO, it might be useful for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution as @Mauker suggested via `onAttach()`

[getActivity() returns null on fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238633/getactivity-returns-null-on-fragment)

but instead of `adding mcontext=getContext();` to each `Fragment` start added this to own class extention of `FragmentPagerAdapter`

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
private Context mContext;

public TabAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}
```