# Trying to call a fragment method from parent activity but the method is not being resolved

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried the solution here:

[Calling a Fragment method from a parent Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity)

But it didn't work for me.

I have this method in my fragment

```
 public void showbutton()
    {
        sup.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

and I'm using this in the parent activity

```
Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
fragment.showbutton();
```

I'm sure it's a silly mistake, I'm still new to Android so forgive me.

Comment: The `Fragment` class does not have your `showbutton()` method. Your specific subclass of `Fragment` does.

Comment: Is there a way for me to call the showbutton method from my fragment sub class in the parent activity? @Mike M.

Comment: Declare and assign `fragment` as your specific subclass, rather than just `Fragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use callback to communicate from fragment to Activity.

```
public interface UserAction {
void showButton();
}
```

In the Fragment implement the Interface

```
@Override
public void showButton() {
        sup.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Then in your activity just call

```
UserAction mUserAction = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
mUserAction.showButton();
```

Comment: you can even add more functions to this interface for communication between activity and fragments

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you are accessing the correct `FragmentManager`, verify that you need to call either `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Secondly, you should `cast` the Fragment to your type. That is,

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
fragment.showbutton();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should typecast using Fragment Name.

i.e

```
YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
fragment.showbutton();
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is regarding to fragment life cycle. You are trying to invoke method of fragment which is closed by android OS. You need to create bool in your fragment and set that to false normally but when you need to show button just create that fragment and load that and update your bool to true.Later on check if that bool is true enable your button else disable it. Happy Coding!