# Add Fragment Tag and Retrive it

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to call Fragment Function from my activity. I am following [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25416259/10106566) Answer for same. Currently My Fragment code is  like below in my HomeActivity.

```
   class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

I want add Tag in this Fragment but does not know how can I do it. I have total three fragment in which I need add Tag so I can retrieve it later. Let me know if someone can help me for achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: I want call compare function from Navigation Drawer click.??? can you more explain it?

Comment: My function is in Fragment. I want call it from Navigation Drawer Menu click.

Comment: means you want to call fragment from HomeActivity menu item click? right?

Comment: @HemantParmar Not Fragment, but function from Fragment. Thanks

Comment: ok than look @NileshRathod ans,it will help you!

Comment: @HemantParmar its giving me null pointer NullPointerException

Comment: call fragment function in activity, do it : `((HomeFragment)this).(yourfragmentMethodName);`