# How do you find a View from a parent activity using findViewByID from a Listener

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I have a custom View in a parent activity that calls...

```
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

...in it's onClickListener. In this new Activity, there is a button callback where I need to call a method in the parent activity's custom View. The same custom View that started the Activity. I tried doing it like so:

```
 ((CustomView) ((LinearLayout) view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_amp_row))
                    .getChildAt(col)).function();
```

I have tried to set the parent activity as a global variable in the new Activity, but the parent is null. I tried setting it in onCreate and onAttachToWindow. I've also tried getParent and using view. I did not see a way to pass the View through the bundle.

How do you go about getting a view from a parent activity?

Comment: *parent activity as a global variable*: don't do it!  About your question: why should you get a view in the parent activity?

Comment: What do you mean by "parent Activity"?

Comment: The activity that contains the custom View that called getContext().startActivity(intent);

Comment: Don't try to make any changes to a user interface other than in the foreground Activity. Pass a simple data type to a background Activity that will result in the view change when that Activity comes to the foreground.

Comment: how do you pass a simple data type to a background Activity?

Comment: Using some form of data storage or by using `startActivityForResult`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that bro if you are extending your parent activity
just because you are inheriting properties of a parent class then you can also have access to its member variables.

Comment: I'm not extending. I have an activity that contains a custom View. This custom view opens a new Activity. This new Activity needs to call a function contained in the custom View.

Comment: Oh, do you mean the new Activity should extend the parent Activity? How would that work? Both activities have their own layout and variables. I only need access to the function in the parent activity.

Answer (score 0):

if you are required to call methods of fragment or activity then you can do that is this way.

**Calling fragments methods from activity**
[Calling a Fragment method from a parent Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity)

**Calling activity methods from fragment**
((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod();

Comment: I only see getCallingActivity()