# NullPointerException when trying to access views from a Fragment

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fragment, rewardedvideoad

I basically want to change the visibility of some xml elements in my fragment when the "onRewardedVideoAdRewarded" method in my MainActivity gets called.

Here is the onRewardedVideoAdRewarded method in my MainActivity.java:

```
 @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(Placement placement) {

        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        myFragment.rewardedVideoFinished();
}
```

and here is the "rewardedVideoFinished" method of my Fragment:

```
public void rewardedVideoFinished (){
 
    myButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ...
}
```

I'm initializing the button in my fragment's onCreateView method like this:

```
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablayout_rewarded,container,false);
myButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

When the Rewarded Video Ad finishes and the "onRewardedVideoAdRewarded" gets called, the app crashes with the following message:

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object
> reference"

I know what NullPointerExceptions are and I know that "myButton" is not initialized when I call it, but why is this the case? I thought with making a new instance of my Fragment it gets initialized.

How can I fix the problem and make the view in my fragment invisible when the rewarded video ad finishes?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly duplication of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity

Comment: It depends on what happens inside the MyFragment  constructor. Could you share here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity